# Spark SQL passing a variable

Tags: sql, select

I have following Spark sql and I want to pass variable to it. How to do that? I tried following way.

```
 sqlContext.sql("SELECT count from mytable WHERE id=$id")
```

Comment: Can you just use [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are almost there just missed `s` :)

```
sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT count from mytable WHERE id=$id")
```

Answer (score 14):

You can pass a string into sql statement like below

```
id = "1"
query = "SELECT count from mytable WHERE id='{}'".format(id)
sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Comment: How can we pass multiple parameters like this where we have id1 , id2 and id3?

Comment: I was constantly getting error with (query = "SELECT count from mytable WHERE id={}".format(id)) for filtering on one column value, while it was working fine with another column value. This fixed my problem. Can you comment on when we should use single quotation  '{}' and when we should avoid single quotation {}?

Comment: this is SQL injection, why would anybody do that?

Comment: @brajeshjaishwal, all code could be understood as some form of injection at some level by someone. The only problem with SQL injection is if you don't have appropriate safeguards for the "user" allow to input values for your variables. If that user is you, then what's not to trust?

Answer (score 5):

Since the accepted answer didn't work for me, I am writing my own answer using string interpolation.

```
sqlContext.sql(s"""SELECT count from mytable WHERE id='${id}'""")
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the f-Strings approach (PySpark):

```
table = 'my_schema.my_table'

df = spark.sql(f'select * from {table}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in spark 2.0 onwards with sparksession

```
spark.sql(s"""SELECT count(*) from mytable WHERE id='$id' """)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a concatenation, with this the engine understands the query, I leave an example:

First:

In a variable inserts the value to pass in the query (in this case is a date)

```
date= spark.range(1).withColumn('date',regexp_replace(date_add(current_date(),-4),"-","")).toPandas().to_string().split()[4]
```

Result = '20220206'

Second:

```
query = '''
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    table
WHERE
    country = '''+' '+date+''' 
'''
df= spark.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the id is in string then the easiest way is the strong formatting. For string, pyspark expects it in the string so provide a single quote as well.

```
 sqlContext.sql(f"SELECT count from mytable WHERE id='{id}'")
```