# Spark SQL pass variable to query

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have looked all over for an answer to this and tried everything. Nothing seems to work. I'm trying to reference a variable assignment within a spark.sql query in python. Running python 3 and spark version 2.3.1.

```
bkt = 1

prime = spark.sql(s"SELECT ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date) as fdr_year, count(*) as counts\
                FROM pwrcrv_tmp\
                where EXTR_CURR_NUM_CYC_DLQ=$bkt\
                and EXTR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in('PS','PT','PD','PC','HV','PA')\
                group by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)\
                order by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)")

prime.show(50)
```

The error:

```
prime = spark.sql(s"SELECT ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date) as fdr_year, count(*) as counts                FROM pwrcrv_tmp         where EXTR_CURR_NUM_CYC_DLQ=$bkt                and EXTR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in('PS','PT','PD','PC','HV','PA')                group by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)                order by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)")
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: bkt = 1

prime = spark.sql("SELECT ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date) as fdr_year, count(*) as counts\
                FROM pwrcrv_tmp\
                where EXTR_CURR_NUM_CYC_DLQ="%bkt%"\
                and EXTR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in('PS','PT','PD','PC','HV','PA')\
                group by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)\
                order by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)")

prime.show(50)

Comment: Is this a question? Not sure why you've posted more code in a comment, as well. Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too.

Comment: First of all `s"..."` is a syntax error - what is that supposed to mean? Secondly, trying to format a string with `$bkt` is not valid python syntax. Look up [String formatting in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Comment: The title of my post is my question. I got the s"..." from this answer which was marked correct on stackoverflow.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284216/spark-sql-passing-a-variable

Comment: @email83 I don't know what language that is, but the answer you're looking for is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284354/5858851

Comment: It's python. Yes, saw and tested that syntax as well.
bkt = "1"

prime = spark.sql("SELECT ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date) as fdr_year, count(*) as counts\
                FROM pwrcrv_tmp\
                where EXTR_CURR_NUM_CYC_DLQ='{}'\
                and EXTR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in('PS','PT','PD','PC','HV','PA')\
                group by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)\
                order by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)").format(id)

prime.show(50) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'format'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct syntax buried in this databricks post.

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/115/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-my-sql-statements.html

You add a lower case f in front of the query and wrap braces around the name of the variable in the query.

```
bkt = 1

prime = spark.sql(f"SELECT ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date) as fdr_year, count(*) as counts\
            FROM pwrcrv_tmp\
            where EXTR_CURR_NUM_CYC_DLQ={bkt}\
            and EXTR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in('PS','PT','PD','PC','HV','PA')\
            group by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)\
            order by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)")


prime.show(50)
```

Comment: Greetings from 2023! I just wanted to add that this same method also works with multiline query strings expressed with triple quotes like: `q = spark.sql(f"""SELECT * FROM {bkt}""")`

Answer (score 0):

### This should work

```
p_filename ='some value'
z='some value'

query = "INSERT into default.loginfordetails (filename,logdesc) values ('{}','{}') ".format(p_filename,z)
 
spark.sql(query)
```

---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since your query do use multi-line query is  it advised as good coding style, to use `""" """` to be easier and avoid slash all together as a good coding style`"\"` that does have a lot of issues or conversion to be parsed in python and pyspark in general or when using nbconvert for notebook to scrip and `variables` in parentheses `{}` inside of query or use `.format(bkt)` :

> option`{}`:

```
bkt=1;
prime = spark.sql(f"""SELECT ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date) as fdr_year, count(*) as counts
                FROM pwrcrv_tmp
                where EXTR_CURR_NUM_CYC_DLQ={bkt}
                and EXTR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in('PS','PT','PD','PC','HV','PA')
                group by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)
                order by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)""")

prime.show(50);
```

> option `.format()`:

```
bkt=1;
prime = spark.sql(f"""SELECT ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date) as fdr_year, count(*) as counts
                FROM pwrcrv_tmp
                where EXTR_CURR_NUM_CYC_DLQ={}
                and EXTR_ACCOUNT_TYPE in('PS','PT','PD','PC','HV','PA')
                group by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)
                order by ((year(fdr_date))*100)+month(fdr_date)""".format(bkt)

prime.show(50);
```